# Ways to secure an anonymous Web API request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a **ASP.NET MVC** (NOT ASP.NET Core) single page application with **angular js** on the front end.

My client (browser) talks to server through ASP.NET Web APIs. Now, the web application is on **https** but **anonymous**. There is no login/ user authentication.

The web app is in the form of a wizard where user can go back and forth and add or update input fields on the web page. The form input values are then updated on the server through Web API.

I'm looking for a way to ***secure*** my Web API calls alone, especially the POST/ PUT requests. In summary, I want to prevent any user calling my Web API directly from POSTMAN or Fiddler. The Web API, though anonymous can be only called from the browser session where the request originated.

- What are options do I have to achieve this?
- Can I use Anti-Forgery token here (without authentication)?
- One way, I can think of achieving this is to add a custom header to each request and store some kind of session key in the header. Then, validate the custom header on every request I received from client. Are any other ways of achieving this out-of-box or some proven library without going for custom solution?
- If I have to go for the above custom solution, what are the pitfalls or potential issues I need to be aware of?

Comment: It took me 20 mins to frame this question. I thought through in depth before asking this question. I don't think this question is too broad by any means. It was down-voted within a min or so. Was it even sufficient time to go through the question? Down voter could have at least commented on what is "too broad" in this. It could help me ask the question better. What else do I need to provide in information here to make this question better?

Comment: Since you cannot do this in general, it's better to add information about reasons you need this and from what threats you are trying to protect, so that we can suggest something different.

Comment: Hi @Evk, the API endpoints are available in javascript code for anyone to see. I can minify the JavaScript but it is still just obfuscation. Since these end-points are visible to end user anyone can call the endpoints to add/update the request data. I get some personal information of a user like his name and age in the form. I want to prevent anyone other than the user (on browser) to update this information.

Comment: But if you have personal information - why don't you just implement authentication as usual, with username/password?

Comment: Cannot go into details. But, my website falls into the pattern where you get information from the user, process it and then give the response based on the information. I think it is a quite common scenario. For example, survey websites.

Comment: Then when survey starts (I will use survey as an example but you can apply this to your case) - you accept user identification information (name, age), store that in database, then attach cookie with random string to the response (and you store that random string together with user information in database). Then all subsequent requests for this survey\user require cookie with the same random string value.

Answer (score 8):

First of all when you remove login and there's no authentication mechanism in your application, there's really no way to **secure** anything, because anyone can access your APIs. I think what you want is to make sure that your APIs are called only from your own website. Unfortunately you can't completely achieve that, since your web APIs are http/https, and anyone, from anywhere (like postman, fiddler, ...) can create a http request and call your API.

All you can do is to make it harder for your API to response to requests, like using Anti-Forgery as you mentioned.

And also I suggest you add a cookie for your application and check that cookie in every request, in this case it's more complicated ( not impossible ) to call your API using Fiddler or Postman.

And last I suggest that you use CORS, so browsers would only allow your domain to call your APIs. So nobody can call your APIs in a browser from different domain.

Comment: Hi @Arvin, I'm not sure how CORS can help here. As per my understanding enabling CORS would allow user agent to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use. Not sure how it would prevent the user to call my API through POSTMAN.

Comment: as I said nothing will prevent user to call APIs through POSTMAN, because your API, angular and also postman are using http protocol. and about CORS, you are right. in your senario it's useful if your API and your angular app are on different domain, then you need to limit the domain with CORS

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. On the Anti-Forgery token, can I use an Anti-Forgery token on a non-authenticated website?

Comment: yes Anti-Forgery has nothing to do with authentication

Comment: That's what I had thought. It looks like Anti-Forgery is the only possible way. Thanks again.

Comment: I just read your comment about having user in your system, if you have user you HAVE TO use authentication, because if you don't someone can change and read all data about all users!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161925/discussion-between-ankit-vijay-and-arvin).

Answer (score 4):

Based on answer from @Arvin and comment from @Evk, here's how I plan to proceed:

- Once, the user starts the `anonymous` session generate a GUID using regular `Guid.NewGuid()` method and save it in DB to identify the request (I'm doing this now). However, as mentioned [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/890/are-guids-safe-for-one-time-tokens/7945#7945),

> GUID can be unique but they are not cryptographically secured.

- Hence, instead of using plain-text GUID, encrypt it with current timestamp as `token` and append it with request query string.
- For every subsequent API request, read the `token` from query string, decrypt it and validate it as follows:

  - Check the timestamp. If the time difference is more than pre-defined time (i.e. token expired), reject the request
  - Validate the unique id (GUID) against DB
- Since, I'm not using plain text GUID anymore, the URI would not easy to guess.

Additionally, with the timestamp, URI is invalidated after sometime. While theoretically it is still possible to call the API through Fiddler but this should make it very difficult for the attacker, if not impossible.

- As a further security measure, I can also add Anti-Forgery token to the request

As per my understanding this helps solving my underlying problem and with this approach, I may not even need add a cookie to secure my anonymous session.

Love to hear from you all if this approach looks good and how can it be improved.

Comment: your overall solutions seems good, just some points I would like to mention. if you are using encryption, it's not such a good idea to send your encryption key(timestamp) to your client. I'm suggesting for you to use `TicketDataFormat` in `Microsoft.Owin.Security` package which generate a ticket for your session and encrypt it, you can also add expiration time to it, and also you don't need to store your tickets in DB, which improve performance

Comment: Despite the fact that you cannot even achieve what you want (Anyone can easily pretend to be a web browser.) You don't have to come up with your custom token verification. You can use an approved method like JWT.

Comment: Your answer perfectly describes the [middleware](https://github.com/huysentruitw/owin-session-middleware) I've created, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043687/1300910)

Answer (score 4):

I also once had the weird need for having session functionality on WebAPI and created an OWIN Session middleware that does exactly what you're aiming for.

The library is called **OwinSessionMiddleware** and is available on [github](https://github.com/huysentruitw/owin-session-middleware) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OwinSessionMiddleware).

**Usage**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSessionMiddleware();

        // other middleware registrations...
        app.UseWebApi();
    }
}
```

You can also pass some [options](https://github.com/huysentruitw/owin-session-middleware#options) to further tweak cookie-name, add a database backed session store (instead of in-memory), add your own session id generator (instead of default id generator which is based on GUID + secure random part generated by `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`).

The unique session id itself is stored as a secure cookie and the session is restored automatically by the middleware on each request.

There are [extension methods](https://github.com/huysentruitw/owin-session-middleware/blob/master/src/OwinSessionMiddleware.WebApi/SessionMiddlewareHttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs) you can call inside your API controller to get and set session data:

```
public SomeApiController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult MyAction()
    {
        var requestCount = Request.GetSessionProperty<int>("RequestCount");

        Request.SetSessionProperty("RequestCount", ++requestCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to send Http cookies using Fiddler?

Comment: Hi @Wouter, looks almost like what I was looking for. I have one question on the session management though. The `ReadMe.md` file mentions that this approach uses in-memory session store. I have not used sessions in my project yet and wanted to avoid as much as possible. I have a load balanced environment, and to manage session on the server I would need to configure out-of-proc mechanism.  Do you know if it is possible to have a custom data store on the server like Raven instead of storing it in session?

Comment: Update: I think I got the answer to my question. Looks like I can have my own implementation of `ISessionStore` and store it wherever I want. Thanks again.

Comment: HI @Legend, it is. But, on secure (`HTTPS`) connection it is cannot be read by an interceptor. And since it is generated through `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` it cannot be easily guessed.

Comment: You could probably configure your load balancer to lock sessions based on the session cookie (often referred as sticky sessions)

Comment: Otherwise you could use a database backed session store if replication/synchronization is fast enough...

Answer (score 1):

Create Anonymous JWT token with some claims related to your scenario, Sign it with some key, Use that as in cookie (Http Only) or As bearer token. To make it little more harder further combine it with some cookies.
1)verify token signature and
2) Verify token expiry time
3) Verify Claim(skey) against cookies(skey)- no database storage required everything is in ur JWT token.