# How to ban deleting user identity from link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hyperlink, identity

How can I make so when somebody tries to delete a user changing the link to "localhost:0000/users/delete/3"? I just want to be able to delete the user after clicking on a delete icon.
Here is the delete icon code:

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the user?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

And here is my delete action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var usersModel = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);
        if (usersModel != null)
        {
            _context.Users.Remove(usersModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
    }
```

Comment: You search something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935231/ways-to-secure-an-anonymous-web-api-request ?

Comment: Isn't there a way to just make so you get redirected from the link, but you don't if you clicked on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to ban deleting user identity from link

> How can I make so when somebody tries to delete a user changing the link to "localhost:0000/users/delete/3"? I just want to be able to delete the user after clicking on a delete icon.

Firstly, please note that if user click the `<a>` tag hyperlink or enter `http(s)://localhost:xxx/users/delete/3` in browser address bar, which would help make a HTTP `GET` request to your `delete` endpoint to delete a specific user record.

If you'd like to prevent browser client user from deleting user's account through URL in address bar, and enable to delete the user by clicking on a delete icon.

To achieve your above requirement, you can try the following workaround.

*Apply `[HttpPost]` and identify your `delete` action that supports the HTTP POST method*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    //...
```

*On MVC view page*

```
<form id="delform" method="post" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID" onclick="DelFunc();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
</form>
```

*Trigger form submit while clicking delete icon*

```
function DelFunc() {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove the user?')) {
        $("#delform").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my life tho!!! I was really in need of that for my project!